# How to make linearLayout scroll without putting it inside scrollview

Tags: scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a `linearlayout` containing

```
textView
imageView
Horizontal recyclerview
TextView
Horizontal Recyclerview
Webview
```

How to make it `scrollable` without putting it inside `scrollview`?

Comment: why do you want to do this

Comment: As my recyclerview contains images and it is not recycling items if i put it inside scrollview. so causing out of memory.

Comment: Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the android developers site, it is recommended not to have RecyclerView / ListView in the ScrollView.

> Never add a RecyclerView or ListView to a scroll view. Doing so
>   results in poor user interface performance and a poor user experience.

For reference 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView

Also, use of NestedScrollView is advised.

Answer (score 0):

Make Linearlayout scrollable without using Scrollview

If you are only using a listview inside a linear layout, then you don't need to use scrollview.Because ListView is scrollable by default.But if you have other components as well then you can separate those in another scrollview.Make sure that ScrollView only uses one direct child layout. Below is a sample code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="#ffffff"> 

   <ListView

    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Linear layouts are not designed to have their contents scrollable - only by embedding it inside a FrameLayout (or a ScrollView, which is a subclass) you can scroll/pan. Why isn't ScrollView an option?

btw, horizontal scroll containers inside vertical scroll containers don't give a good UI/UX, but there are other ways to achieve what you're after. Please give us more details and I'm sure we'll be able to help you